# Chrome to download Gmail attachments to a different place (osx)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gmail

I'm using Chrome and Gmail. When I download stuff from the web, Chrome automatically puts it in *Downloads*, which is fine. However, I'm aware that everything I download from Gmail is in the cloud anyway and so I don't really need it taking up space on my hard drive as well.

Is there a way to have Gmail attachements automatically download to a different folder, say, *Downloads\Gmail*? That way I could regularly purge the ones that won't be useful for a while. (Yes, I'm aware that Word documents and the like often get changed after they arrive, I'm more focused on images, pdfs, and zip files.)

I'd be quite happy with a background problem quietly scanning downloaded file and performing actions based on where they are from...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll have to do that manually if you're using Chrome. You can change settings so that Chrome always asks you where to save a downloaded file though. [Documentation](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95574).

Using Firefox, it seems the [Automatic Save Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/automatic-save-folder/) addon might help you:

> This extension allows you to specify different save folders according
>   to filters based on the filename and/or domain.

Comment: +1 for solving the problem exactly, shame it's not quite the browser I was looking for :(

Comment: @Joe: Firefox is the king of customizability. But I understand why you prefer Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you can download a lot of images, links, audio & video (HTML 5) etc from the web and save it to GDrive using Chrome with the Chrome extension called **Save to Drive**.

It will add an option to the right click contextual menu that lets you send items directly to your Google Drive. A notification will be sent to your desktop when the item has been succesfully saved (depending on its size)

A review of it was carried out on November 26th 2012 for Addictive Tips which can be read here:

http://www.addictivetips.com/web/quickly-save-images-links-audio-video-to-google-drive-from-chrome/

Its link in the Chrome Web Store can be found here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-drive/deoibeabfchdpckcmamaadeccohilbkp#detail/save-to-drive/deoibeabfchdpckcmamaadeccohilbkp